# Finding "Score Triplets"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm a highschool mathematics teacher and I've been playing the following game with students

Three one digit numbers are written up on the board. Then the students are required to construct the integers from $1$ to $20$ with the following rules

1. Each number in the set can be used a maximum of once
2. No other numbers can be used
3. Only the symbols $\times , \div, +,-,!$ ,^,$\sqrt{}$, ^$\sqrt{}$, and brackets can be used. Concatenation is not valid.
4. To avoid trivial solutions all three numbers in the triplet must be used to construct their respective totals

Notes:

- ^ means numbers can be used as powers, and ^$\sqrt{}$ means you can use numbers as a part of a surd. So if the set is $\{2,3,8\}$ then $2^3$ and $\sqrt[3]8$ are both valid.
- To keep with the spirit of not complicating the operations, factorials can be used and nested, but multifactorials like $5!!=5\times3\times1$ are not valid.
- Rule 4 means that if your triplet is $\{2,3,7\}$ the construction for $7$ can't be $7=7$, but instead could be $7=7^{3-2}$. This is only the case for the three numbers in the triplet, all other totals are not bound by this rule.

A triplet is considered a "score triplet" if every number from $1$ to $20$ is constructible

An example of a score triplet is $\{2,3,8\}$
$1=3-2$
$2=\sqrt{2\times\sqrt[3]8} $
$3=8-2-3$
$4=8 \div 2$
$5=2+3$
$6=2\times 3$
$7=8+2-3$
$8=8\times(3-2)$
$9=3^2$
$10=8+2$
$11=8+3$
$12=8+3!-2$
$13=8\times2-3$
$14=8+3!$
$15=(2+3)!\div8$
$16=8\times2$
$17=3^2+8$
$18=(8\div2)!-3!$
$19=8\times2+3$
$20=3!\times2+8$

However other triplets I have not been able to prove are score triplets, I'm unable to make $19$ from the set $\{1,7,9\}$ for example.

Of the $84$ unique sets of non-repeating triplets (e.g, excluding $\{2,2,5\}$) I've been able to show $33$ are score triplets with a number of others one or two numbers short. I have no idea how to formalize this further and am unsure if some sets just aren't score triplets or if through some monstrous combination of nested factorials, surds, and powers all sets are in fact score triplets.

Ultimately the question becomes;

Is there a way of proving a set of three numbers is not a score triplet?

I know this problem is a little parochial, but I'd love to get some thoughts on this since I can't seem to find information on it anywhere else.

Comment: It says you must use all three numbers but you have $1=3-2$ which doesn't use the 8.

Comment: The requirement for all three numbers is only for the 3 numbers within the set. The primary reason for this was to avoid three trivial cases for every set.

Comment: The only way to check this systematically would be to write a program.

Comment: I wrote a program which checks these, but so far the program only gets eight out of 84 as being complete. For example, for 7,8,9 it says that it cannot find [3 5 11 12 13 14 18 19 20]. Could you add a list of which triplets you think are OK so I can check this program against your list?

Comment: Absolutely, I can currently get 129, 134, 135, 139, 149, 159, 169, 235, 237, 238, 245, 247, 249, 256, 258, 259, 279, 289, 345, 347, 348, 349, 359, 456, 457, 458, 459, 469, 479, 489, 569, 579, 589. I can scan through full lists of my working tomorrow if that will help. For 789 I have everything except 19 and 20.

Comment: All the others you list there I got using the fact that sqrt(9)=3 as a part of the equation.

Comment: OK we can use square roots? I missed that.

Comment: Some examples of failures: For 159, I can't get 17. For 237 I can't get 18. For 256 I can't get 14. For 359 I can't get 16. For 135 I can't get 13 and 17. What did I miss?

Comment: Those are complicated examples. 17=sqrt(5!+1)+sqrt(9)! , 14=sqrt(6!÷5)+2 , 16=((3!)!÷5)÷9 , 13=sqrt([3!]!÷5)+1 , 17=sqrt(5!+1)+3!

Comment: I see. Unary operators are a huge pain so I didn't implement all of the possible combinations of square roots and factorials. I'll have to think of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a computer program to compute these. It is still missing doubled factorials so it doesn't get everything.

[Run it online here](https://go.dev/play/p/LTFJcyyfdsc)

Full code:

````
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
)

type binop func(a, b int) (d int, ok bool)

type fac [5]bool

func add(a, b int) (int, bool) {
    return a + b, true
}

func sub(a, b int) (int, bool) {
    return a - b, true
}

func revSub(a, b int) (int, bool) {
    return b - a, true
}

const small = 0.000001

func surd(a, b int) (int, bool) {
    if a == 1 || b == 1 {
        return -1, false
    }
    root := math.Pow(float64(a), 1/float64(b))
    if math.Abs(root-math.Round(root)) < small {
        return int(math.Round(root)), true
    }
    return -1, false
}

func pow(a, b int) (p int, q bool) {
    p = 1
    for i := 0; i < b; i++ {
        p *= a
    }
    return p, true
}

func mul(a, b int) (int, bool) {
    return a * b, true
}

func div(a, b int) (int, bool) {
    if b == 0 || a%b != 0 {
        return 0, false
    }
    return a / b, true
}

func revDiv(a, b int) (int, bool) {
    return div(b, a)
}

var ops = []binop{
    add,
    sub,
    revSub,
    surd,
    pow,
    mul,
    div,
    revDiv,
}

var names = []string{
    "+",
    "-",
    "<->",
    "root",
    "^",
    "x",
    "/",
    "</>",
}

func factorial(a int) (f int) {
    if a > 10 {
        return a
    }
    f = 1
    for a > 1 {
        f *= a
        a--
    }
    return f
}

func checkabc(s *scoTrip, a, b, c int) {
    oa, ob, oc := a, b, c
    if s.f[0] {
        a = factorial(a)
    }
    if s.f[1] {
        b = factorial(b)
    }
    if s.f[2] {
        c = factorial(c)
    }
    for i, oi := range ops {
        ab, ok := oi(a, b)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        if s.f[3] {
            ab = factorial(ab)
        }
        var abr int
        abr, s.abt = rootable(ab)
        if s.abt {
            addFound(s, oa, ob, 0, i, 0, abr)
        }
        addFound(s, oa, ob, 0, i, 0, ab)
        for j, oj := range ops {
            abc, ok := oj(ab, c)
            if !ok {
                continue
            }
            if s.f[4] {
                abc = factorial(abc)
            }
            addFound(s, oa, ob, oc, i, j, abc)
            if s.abt {
                abc, ok := oj(abr, c)
                if !ok {
                    continue
                }
                if s.f[4] {
                    abc = factorial(abc)
                }
                addFound(s, oa, ob, oc, i, j, abc)
            }
        }
    }
}

func rootable(a int) (int, bool) {
    if a == 1 {
        return -1, false
    }
    if a == 4 {
        return 2, true
    }
    if a == 9 {
        return 3, true
    }
    z := int(math.Round(math.Sqrt(float64(a))))
    if z*z == a {
        return z, true
    }
    return -1, false
}

func checkabcroot(s *scoTrip, a, b, c int) {
    s.at = false
    s.bt = false
    s.ct = false
    checkabc(s, a, b, c)
    var ar, br, cr int // square roots of a,b,c
    ar, s.at = rootable(a)
    br, s.bt = rootable(b)
    cr, s.ct = rootable(c)
    // Cannot have all three since a==4, b==9 then c=/=4,9
    if s.at && s.bt && s.ct {
        panic("a,b,c=4,9,?")
    }
    if !s.at && !s.bt && !s.ct {
        return
    }
    if s.at {
        checkabc(s, ar, b, c)
        if s.bt {
            checkabc(s, ar, br, c)
        }
        if s.ct {
            checkabc(s, ar, b, cr)
        }
    }
    if s.bt {
        checkabc(s, a, br, c)
        if s.ct {
            checkabc(s, a, br, cr)
        }
    }
    if s.ct {
        checkabc(s, a, b, cr)
    }
}

func facs(fi int) (f fac) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        f[i] = (fi%2 == 1)
        fi /= 2
    }
    return f
}

func plainChecks(s *scoTrip, a, b, c int) {
    checkabcroot(s, a, b, c)
    checkabcroot(s, b, a, c)
    checkabcroot(s, c, a, b)
    checkabcroot(s, c, b, a)
    checkabcroot(s, b, c, a)
    checkabcroot(s, a, c, b)
}

type scoTrip struct {
    found      []bool
    f          fac
    at, bt, ct bool
    abt        bool
}

func check(a, b, c int) bool {
    fmt.Printf("Checking %d, %d, %d:\n", a, b, c)
    var s scoTrip
    s.found = make([]bool, 21)
    for fi := 0; fi < 32; fi++ {
        s.f = facs(fi)
        plainChecks(&s, a, b, c)
    }
    all := true
    missing := make([]int, 0)
    for i, f := range s.found {
        if i == 0 {
            continue
        }
        if !f {
            all = false
            missing = append(missing, i)
        }
    }
    if all {
        if verbose {
            fmt.Printf("They were all found.\n")
        }
        return true
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Missing %v\n", missing)
        return false
    }
}

func pf(f bool) string {
    if f {
        return "!"
    }
    return ""
}

func root(f bool) string {
    if f {
        return "√"
    }
    return ""
}

func printA(s *scoTrip, a int) (p string) {
    if s.at {
        p += fmt.Sprintf("√%d", a*a)
    } else {
        p += fmt.Sprintf("%d", a)
    }
    p += pf(s.f[0])
    return p
}

func printB(s *scoTrip, b int) (p string) {
    if s.bt {
        p += fmt.Sprintf("√%d", b*b)
    } else {
        p += fmt.Sprintf("%d", b)
    }
    p += pf(s.f[1])
    return p
}

func printC(s *scoTrip, c int) (p string) {
    if s.ct {
        p += fmt.Sprintf("√%d", c*c)
    } else {
        p += fmt.Sprintf("%d", c)
    }
    p += pf(s.f[2])
    return p
}

func addFound(s *scoTrip, a, b, c, i, j, d int) {
    if d < 1 || d > 20 {
        return
    }
    if s.found[d] {
        return
    }
    abroot := ""
    if s.abt {
        abroot = "√"
    }
    if verbose {
        if c == 0 {
            fmt.Printf("Found %d as %s%s %s %s\n", d,
                abroot,
                printA(s, a),
                names[i],
                printB(s, b))
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Found %d as %s(%s %s %s) %s %s %s %s\n", d,
                abroot,
                printA(s, a), names[i],
                printB(s, b), names[j],
                pf(s.f[3]),
                printC(s, c), pf(s.f[4]))
        }
    }
    s.found[d] = true
}

var verbose = true

func main() {
    var lexi = []int{129, 134, 135, 139, 149, 159, 169, 235, 237, 238, 245, 247, 249, 256, 258, 259, 279, 289, 345, 347, 348, 349, 359, 456, 457, 458, 459, 469, 479, 489, 569, 579, 589}
    verbose = false
    if true {
        check(1, 3, 5)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    ok := 0
    total := 0
    for i := 1; i <= 7; i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j <= 8; j++ {
            for k := j + 1; k <= 9; k++ {
                isOk := false
                if check(i, j, k) {
                    ok++
                    isOk = true
                }
                l := i*100 + j*10 + k
                found := false
                for _, le := range lexi {
                    if l == le {
                        found = true
                    }
                }
                if found {
                    if isOk {
                        fmt.Printf("Agree\n")
                    } else {
                        fmt.Printf("Failed with %d\n", l)
                    }
                }
                total++
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Found %d of total of %d\n", ok, total)
}

```
````